# Revision control tool for Apache server?

Tags: apache, controls, revision

I've got an online web server (Apache/PHP/MySQL) that is hosted by [Infomaniak](http://www.infomaniak.com/?language=english). I'm going to work on a website project together with 2 people.
What I want is to extract a tool on my web server that would enable revision control (SVN or Git) in order for each other of us to work on the same code located on my web server. Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mod_dav_svn` is the apache module to enable SVN access through HTTP using apache web server. However, a shared hosting service like Infomaniak may not allow you to install modules of your choice. Summary is - you may not be able to use any existing tool for this purpose as long as you use shared hosting service.

You may consider using a free SVN/git service like [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/home).